# Jagged 2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to create an array with the following structure

```
D
C C
B B B
A A A A
```

Which will be N x N but split diagonally. Initially, all I know is the bottom row essentially just:

```
string[,] table = new string[n,];
```

How can I build on this structure so that when I get to the next row I can declare how many elements it has? Would it be something along the lines of:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    table[i] = new string[--n]
}
```

Comment: That looks about right to me, though I don't know about the predecrement. What's your question? Have you compiled it? We generally won't act as compilers for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[,]` syntax creates [multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), not [jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). For the latter, you would need to do this:

```
int n = 4;
string[][] table = new string[n][];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    table[i] = new string[n-i];
```

Btw. you really don’t want to decrement `n` while looping in a loop with the condition `i < n` (or `i <= n`).